# Laravel : Order BY Month and Year

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent, sql-order-by

Hello Please how to order by year and month using the some the field of artibute 
My code :

```
\App\User::select(DB::raw('SUM(Comptabilise)* -1 as `data`'), DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(date, '%m-%Y') new_date"),  DB::raw('MONTHNAME(date) month'))
        ->groupby('month')
        ->orderBy('YEAR(new_date)', 'ASC')
        ->orderBy('MONTH(new_date)', 'ASC')
        ->get();
```

I want to order by new_date from min date to max like from 05-2018 to 10-2019 
Please Could you help me to do it and thanks ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fix it by this code and thanks for your time !

```
\App\User::select(DB::raw('SUM(Comptabilise)* -1 as `data`'), DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y') year"),DB::raw('MONTH(date) months'),  DB::raw('MONTHNAME(date) month'))
        ->groupby('month')
        ->orderBy('year', 'ASC')
        ->orderBy('months', 'ASC')
        ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that you `group by` clause does not seem right.

You are grouping by month name. So if your data spreads over more than 12 months, you will still end up with 12 records only the resultset, with records having the same month but different years grouped together.

You should add the year to the group by clause to, like so:

```
\App\User::select(DB::raw('SUM(Comptabilise)* -1 as `data`'), DB::raw("YEAR(date) year"),DB::raw('MONTH(date) months'),  DB::raw('MONTHNAME(date) month'))
        ->groupBy('year')
        ->groupBy('months')
        ->orderBy('year', 'ASC')
        ->orderBy('months', 'ASC')
        ->get();
```

Note: MySQL has a `YEAR()` function, I used it in the query because it's more consistent with  `MONTH()` that using a string conversion method like `DATE_FORMAT()`.